Django Formset Validation Issue: "This field is required" Error for Formset Fields
enter code hereI am  working on a Django project that involves using a ModelForm for a Driver model and an inlineformset_factory for a related DriverTrip model. The formset is supposed to dynamically add trip details in the frontend, and I'm encountering a persistent validation error when trying to submit the formset.
models.py:
from django.db import models

class Driver(models.Model):
    staff_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    driver_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    duty_card_no = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class DriverTrip(models.Model):
    driver = models.ForeignKey(Driver, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    route_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    trip_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pick_up_time = models.TimeField()
    drop_off_time = models.TimeField()
    shift_time = models.TimeField()
    head_count = models.IntegerField()

forms.py:
from django import forms
from django.forms import inlineformset_factory
from .models import Driver, DriverTrip

class DriverForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Driver
        fields = ['staff_id', 'driver_name', 'duty_card_no']

DriverTripFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    Driver,
    DriverTrip,
    fields=('route_name', 'trip_type', 'pick_up_time', 'drop_off_time', 'shift_time', 'head_count'),
    extra=1,
    can_delete=True
)

views.py:
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import DriverForm, DriverTripFormSet
from .models import Driver

def enter_head_count(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        driver_form = DriverForm(request.POST)
        trip_formset = DriverTripFormSet(request.POST)

        if driver_form.is_valid() and trip_formset.is_valid():
            driver, created = Driver.objects.get_or_create(
                staff_id=driver_form.cleaned_data['staff_id'],
                defaults={
                    'driver_name': driver_form.cleaned_data['driver_name'],
                    'duty_card_no': driver_form.cleaned_data['duty_card_no'],
                }
            )

            if not created:
                driver.driver_name = driver_form.cleaned_data['driver_name']
                driver.duty_card_no = driver_form.cleaned_data['duty_card_no']
                driver.save()

            trip_formset.instance = driver
            trip_formset.save()
            return redirect('success')
        else:
            print("Driver Form Errors:", driver_form.errors)
            print("Trip Formset Errors:", trip_formset.errors)
    else:
        driver_form = DriverForm()
        trip_formset = DriverTripFormSet()

    return render(request, 'duty/enter_head_count.html', {
        'driver_form': driver_form,
        'trip_formset': trip_formset,
    })
  

Html:
<
form method="post" id="driver-trip-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ driver_form.as_p }}
    {{ trip_formset.management_form }}
    <div id="trip-entries">
        {% for form in trip_formset %}
            <div class="form-row trip-form-container">
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.route_name.label_tag }} 
                    {{ form.route_name }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.trip_type.label_tag }}
                    {{ form.trip_type }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.pick_up_time.label_tag }}
                    {{ form.pick_up_time }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.drop_off_time.label_tag }}
                    {{ form.drop_off_time }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.shift_time.label_tag }}
                    {{ form.shift_time }}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.head_count.label_tag }}
                    {{ form.head_count }}
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div id="button-container" class="button-container">
        <div id="add-row" class="add-icon">+</div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="submit-button">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>

JavaScript:
// JavaScript for dynamically adding formset fields
$(document).ready(function() {
    var tripCount = {{ trip_formset.total_form_count|default:0 }};
    $('#add-row').click(function() {
        var newRow = `
            <div class="form-row trip-form-container">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Route Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="drivertrip_set-${tripCount}-route_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Route Name" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Type</label>
                    <select name="drivertrip_set-${tripCount}-trip_type" class="form-control" required>
                        <option value="inbound">Inbound</option>
                        <option value="outbound">Outbound</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Pick Up Time</label>
                    <input type="time" name="drivertrip_set-${tripCount}-pick_up_time" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Drop Off Time</label>
                    <input type="time" name="drivertrip_set-${tripCount}-drop_off_time" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Shift Time</label>
                    <input type="time" name="drivertrip_set-${tripCount}-shift_time" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Head Count</label>
                    <input type="number" name="drivertrip_set-${tripCount}-head_count" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Head Count" required>
                </div>
                <div class="remove-trip-container">
                    <span class="remove-trip">Remove</span>
                </div>
            </div>`;
        $('#trip-entries').append(newRow);
        $('#id_drivertrip_set-TOTAL_FORMS').val(++tripCount);
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.remove-trip', function() {
        $(this).closest('.trip-form-container').remove();
        tripCount--;
        $('#id_drivertrip_set-TOTAL_FORMS').val(tripCount);
    });
});

Problem Description:
When I try to submit the form, I encounter the error:
Formset Errors: [{'route_name': ['This field is required.'], 'pick_up_time': ['This field is required.'], 'drop_off_time': ['This field is required.'], 'shift_time': ['This field is required.'], 'head_count': ['This field is required.'], 'trip_type': ['This field is required.']}]
This error appears when using the formset to dynamically add multiple trips. If a user manually fills in all details without using the autocomplete feature, the validation passes.
The backend expects formset field names like drivertrip_set-0-route_name, but dynamically added fields are indexed based on tripCount, e.g., drivertrip_set-0-route_name, drivertrip_set-1-route_name, etc.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!.
